# Unable to find item in batch Absinthe Dataloader

Tags: elixir, ecto, absinthe

After upgrading absinthe from 1.4.12 to 1.5.2, ecto from 2.1 to 3.0 and dataloader from 1.0.2 to 1.0.7 I've been having some issues with dataloader not finding items in batch. I tried to follow the steps pointed by deepankar-j at https://github.com/absinthe-graphql/absinthe/issues/746 to see if there was something related and reached to the PR that fixes the use_parent: false as default issue (https://github.com/absinthe-graphql/absinthe/pull/891) but couldn't solve my problem.

I'm following exactly the documentation to apply the dataloader to avoid N+1.

Some further details:
When I query for a specific field in my application the batch 'breaks'.
This is how I'm applying the dataloader and using the result to sort. When query for this field:

```
operations {
      id
    }
```

Implemented like this:

```
field :operations, list_of(:theme_clothing_operation), resolve: dataloader(Db,
  :theme_clothing_operations, callback: fn(operations, _parent, _args) ->
    {:ok, operations |> Enum.sort_by(fn(operation) -> operation.id end)}
  end
)
```

[I get the following error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy7Sz.png)

But when i remove that field query it works. I'm not sure if I provided enough details or if it is in some way possible to help with only this, but I really appreciate some help or some clues of what might be happening.